# Unexpected bash sort behavior

Tags: bash, sorting

If I create a text file containing the following lines:

```
>TESTTEXT_10000000
>TESTTEXT_1000000
>TESTTEXT_10000002
>TESTTEXT_10000001
```

and perform `sort myfile`, my output is

```
>TESTTEXT_1000000
>TESTTEXT_10000000
>TESTTEXT_10000001
>TESTTEXT_10000002
```

However, if I append /1 and /2 to my lines the sort output changes drastically, and I do not know why.

Input:

```
>TESTTEXT_10000000/1
>TESTTEXT_1000000/1
>TESTTEXT_10000002/1
>TESTTEXT_10000001/1
```

Output:

```
>TESTTEXT_10000000/1
>TESTTEXT_1000000/1
>TESTTEXT_10000001/1
>TESTTEXT_10000002/1
```

Input:

```
>TESTTEXT_10000000/2
>TESTTEXT_1000000/2
>TESTTEXT_10000002/2
>TESTTEXT_10000001/2
```

Output:

```
>TESTTEXT_10000000/2
>TESTTEXT_10000001/2
>TESTTEXT_1000000/2
>TESTTEXT_10000002/2
```

Is the forward slash being recognised as a seperator? using --field-sperator did not alter the behaviour. If so, why is 1000000/2 in between the 1000001/2 and 1000002/2 entries? Using the human sort, numeric sort or other options never brought about consistency. Can anyone help me out here?

:edit:
Because it seems to be relevant, considering the answers, the value of LC_ALL on this machine is `en_GB.UTF-8`

Comment: Try this: `LC_ALL=C sort file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is before `0` in your locale. Using `LC_ALL=C` or other locale will properly not change anything.

In your use case you would properly be able to use `-V`ersion sort:

```
sort -V myfile
```

Alternative can you specify the separator and keys to sort on:

```
sort -t/ -k1,1 myfile
```

Comment: Oddly enough, LC_ALL=C did solve my issue and made the ordering consistent. However, the sort -V option also solved the issue without changing the locale, so I'll accept this answer.